# Force IE8 open popups in new tab focused

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs, popup, focus

I already have the popup opening in a new tab. I need to know how to open the tab focused instead of in the background.

EDIT: Tools -> Internet Options -> Tabs -> Settings -> Check "Always switch to new tabs when created".
I'll be answering my own question when stackoverflow time is up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ools -> Internet Options -> Tabs -> Settings -> Check "Always switch to new tabs when created"